# How to draw the following picture on tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, tikz-graphdrawing, tikz-graphs, tikzpagenodes

[image]

Is there any way to do this without drawing every single circles?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please do not forget to provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so that others do not have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This draws the circles in a nested loop.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0,0) --  (3,0) node[right]{$\mathsf{Y}$}
  (0,0,0) --  (0,3) node[above]{$\mathsf{Z}$}
  (0,0,0) --  (-135:3) node[below left]{$\mathsf{X}$}
  foreach \Angle in {0,...,23}
  {foreach[evaluate={(\Radius>2?1:0)||(Mod(\Angle,4)==0)} as \myflag] 
    \Radius in {1,...,7}
   {\ifnum\myflag=1\relax
    (\Angle*15-2:\Radius*0.36) circle[radius=2pt]
    \fi}};
 \draw[dashed,nodes={inner sep=10pt}] 
    (0,0,3) node[left]{$v_x$} -- (2,0,3) edge (2,2,3)
     -- (2,0,0) node[below]{$v_y$}
     (2,2,3) node[below right]{$v_z$};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A great job. Missing the cube with the label.